# loopback 3 string not matched with and condition

Tags: regex, mongodb, loopback

i am trying to filter with multiple value in loopback 3. 'AND condition' is not working. Numeric value filter working good but string value not matched.

**this is my  condition is now :**

```
{ "and": [{ "id": { "neq": "5d146f1f7a62651b8162fcf3" } }, 
{ "gender": "male" }, { "age": { "between": [16, 60] } }, 
{ "interestId": { "inq": ["5d11c0ce59e2b64e8dc12956", "5d11c0e259e2b64e8dc12958", "5d11c08659e2b64e8dc12953", "5d11c01759e2b64e8dc1294b", "5d11c03759e2b64e8dc1294d"] } }, 
{ "location": { "near": { "lat": 26.8574194, "lng": 75.7977288 }, "maxDistance": 6, "unit": "kilometers" } },
  { "maritalStatus": { "like": {} } }, { "college": { "like": {} } },
  { "career": { "like": {} } }, { "currentJob": { "like": {} } }, 
  { "height": { "between": [50, 89] } }, { "weight": { "between": [72, 192] } }, { "bodyBuild": "Slim" }] }
```

String value is not push in array.

```
if (interestId.highSchool && interestId.highSchool !="") {
          var highschool = new RegExp('.*' + interestId.highSchool + '.*', "i");
          query.and.push({
            highSchool: { like: highschool }
          })
        }
```

where is issue i don't understand. if i did't pass string value it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:-

```
if (interestId.highSchool && interestId.highSchool !="") {      
  query.and.push({
     highSchool: {regexp: new RegExp('.*' + interestId.highSchool + '.*', "i")}
  })
}
```